# What are pros and cons of using same constant value in test method?

Tags: tdd

I am very new to TDD. I am reading [TDD By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) and it says "never try to use the same constant to mean more than one thing" and it show an example of `Plus()` method.

In my opinion, there is no difference between Plus(1, 1) which uses same constant value and Plus(1, 2). I want to know what are pros and cons of using same constant value in test method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misinterprete that statement. What the author (imho) is trying to convey is that following code is a recipe for disaster.

```
const SomeRandomValue = 32;
...
// Plus testcase
Plus(SomeRandomValue, SomeRandomValue)
...
// Divide testcase
Divide(SomeRandomValue, SomeRandomValue)
```

You have two testcases reusing a **none descriptive** constant. There is no way to know that by changing `SomeRandomValue` to `0` your testsuite will fail.

A better naming would be something like

```
const AdditionValue = 32;
const DivisorValue = 32;
...
// Plus testcase
Plus(AdditionValue, AdditionValue)
...
// Divide testcase
Divide(DivisorValue, DivisorValue)
```

where it should be obvious as to what the constants are used for.You should not get *to* hung up on the idea of code reuse when creating testcases.

Or to put it in other words:

> I don't see anything wrong with reusing the `DivisorValue` constant in multiple testcases > but there is definitly something wrong trying to shoehorn one value into a none descriptive variable just in the name of code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same value in your test - as in `Plus(1, 1)` - your code could work for the wrong reason.  Here is an implementation of `Plus` that will pass such a test, but fail a test with different values.

```
public int Plus (int a, int b) {
    return a + a;
}
```

A test that avoids this risk is a better test than one which lets errors like these slip through.